# Winsock2 Error: Server crashes when connecting to client

Tags: c++, winsock2

I am trying to make my server assign client ID's, yet whenever I connect the client to the server, the server crashes.

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>

#define PORT 25444
#define MAX_CLIENTS 2
#define BUFLEN 512

int main()
{

    SOCKET s;

    unsigned int Max = MAX_CLIENTS - 1;
    unsigned int ID[ Max ];

    std::string Address[ Max ];

    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;

    int slen, recv_len;

    char buf[ BUFLEN ];

    WSADATA wsa;

    slen = sizeof( si_other );

    if ( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), & wsa ) != 0 )
    {

        std::cout << "NETWORK ERROR: Failed to initialise. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    if ( ( s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {

        std::cout << "NETWORK ERROR: Failed to create socket. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    if ( bind( s, ( struct sockaddr * ) & server, sizeof( server ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {

        std::cout << "NETWORK ERROR: Failed to bind to port. Error Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    while( 1 )
    {

        bool AddClient;
        unsigned int TimesLooped;

        memset( buf, '\0', BUFLEN );

        if ( ( recv_len = recvfrom( s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, ( struct sockaddr * ) & si_other, & slen ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {

            std::cout << "NETWORK ERROR: Failed to read from the port. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

        }
        else
        {

            TimesLooped = 0;

            for ( int i = 0; i <= Max; i++ )
            {

                if ( inet_ntoa( si_other.sin_addr ) != Address[ i ] )
                {

                    AddClient = true;

                }
                else
                {

                    AddClient = false;

                    i = Max;

                }

                TimesLooped++;

            }

            if ( AddClient )
            {

                Address[ TimesLooped ] = inet_ntoa( si_other.sin_addr );
                ID[ TimesLooped ] = TimesLooped;

            }

        }

        std::cout << "NETWORK: Received packet from " << inet_ntoa( si_other.sin_addr ) << ":" << ntohs( si_other.sin_port ) << "( Client ID: " << ID[ TimesLooped ] << " )" << "\n";
        std::cout << "NETWORK: Data: " << buf << "\n";

        if ( sendto( s, buf, recv_len, 0, ( struct sockaddr * ) & si_other, slen ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {

            std::cout << "NETWORK ERROR: Failed to send data through the port. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

        }

    }

    closesocket( s );

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;

}
```

Client:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define IP "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 25444
#define BUFLEN 512

using namespace std;

void SendPacket( string message )
{

    struct sockaddr_in si_other;

    int s, slen = sizeof( si_other );

    char buf[ BUFLEN ];

    char msg[ BUFLEN ];

    strcpy( msg, message.c_str() );

    WSADATA wsa;

    if ( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), & wsa ) != 0 )
    {

        cout << "ERROR: Network failed to initialise. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    if ( ( s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {

        cout << "ERROR: Network failed to create socket. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    memset( ( char * ) & si_other, 0, sizeof( si_other ) );
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr( IP );

    if ( sendto( s, msg, strlen( msg ), 0, ( struct sockaddr * ) & si_other, slen ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {

        cout << "ERROR: Network failed to send data through the port. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    memset( buf, '\0', BUFLEN );

    if ( recvfrom( s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, ( struct sockaddr * ) & si_other, & slen ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {

        cout << "ERROR: Network failed to read from the port. Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    }

    closesocket( s );

    WSACleanup();

}

int main()
{

    SendPacket( "Test" );

    return 0;

}
```

I wish to be able to have client ID's so that I can keep track of which IP is which and then when I need to send packets to the client, I can do so by referring to the the client ID via `Address[ ID ];`. The server and client run fine without the code for client ID's. Please help. Any suggestions to how to improve the code or other ways to do it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your Address array only has one element. MAX_CLIENTS is 2. Max is 2 - 1, or 1, and so only Address[0] is valid. You loop from 0 to 1, so every time you reference index 1, I would not be surprised to see a crash.

Take a look at std::map, for example [here.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html) A dictionary will handle the searching for you. I would use std::map to handle the table of client IDs.

Also, your client key is only using the IP address, and not the client's port. If two clients connect from the same IP address, they will share your client ID. You may want to include the port number in the ID string.

Comment: I figured that arrays start at 0 not one, so when I defined MAX_CLIENTS at 2, i decremented it in Max so that the only available ones would be 0 and 1. I will look into std::map and improve the code, and I didn't think about clients on the same IP, so I will definitely add it. But I am curious to how 1 is invalid?

Comment: If you create an array of size 1, then the only index in it is 0, since the indexes start at zero. If you have an array a of size 1, then the only valid index is a[0]. If you have an array a of size 2, then the valid indexes are at a[0] and a[1].

Comment: Ah ok. I though that if I put 1 in, it would allow for 0 and 1, and if I put 0 in, it would only be 0. So I assumed that the number I entered would be the max it could go to. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction